# Downgrade cmake to 3.24.0 for cli on MacOS

Tags: cmake

First of all my motivation: I want to downgrade cmake on my M1 Mac because there are several build issues building openCV for iOS on MacOS for crosscompiling with the most recent cmake version.

Because it seems that cmake 3.24.0 fixes the problem, I uninstalled my cmake version and tried to install the cli for version 3.24.0 using
`brew install cmake@3.24`. But it seems that there is no formula (`Error: No formulae or casks found for cmake@3.24..`). Therefore I downloaded the `.dmg` file from the previous release, but this only contains an application.

How can I install the command line interface for cmake 3.24.0 on my MacOS?

**Edit1:**

Same result for `brew install cmake@3.24.0`.

`brew doctor` results in `#Your system is ready to brew.`.

Comment: Do you need to specify the patch version number in your command? Ex. `brew install cmake@3.24.0`? Related: list of versions: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/dfabfaf2c845c5b601e3b05ca7478cccdaf098c4/Formula/cmake.rb

Comment: Same error like ```brew install cmake@3.24```, it seems like there is no formula found by brew.

Comment: I suggested with a ".0" at the end...

Comment: Yes I tried that too, same result.

Answer (score -2):

```
export PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/:$PATH"
```

in your .bashrc or .zshrc